# Parsing time format

Tags: php

How do I calculate the input to time in seconds, when the input is in different formats as shown in the example output below?

With this format, all parts are optional:

```
5d 4h 3m 2s -> 5 days, 4 hours, 3 minutes and 2 seconds
4h 2s -> 4 hours and 2 seconds
3m -> 3 minutes
```

With this format, parts are sometimes optional:

```
05: 04: 03: 02 -> 5 days, 4 hours, 3 minutes and 2 seconds
4:03:02 -> 4 hours, 3 minutes and 2 seconds
05: 00: 03: 02 -> 5 days, 3 minutes and 2 seconds
02 -> 2 seconds
```

I'd like to get this output:

```
> php time.php 1d 6h 20m 2s
> 109.202 seconds
> php time.php 3:50
> 230 seconds
> php time.php 4: 23: 45: 02
> 431.102 seconds
> php time.php 23m
> 1.380 seconds
```

So far I made it possible to convert input seconds to a time format, but after 5 hours of trying to make the above question work I kind of gave up:

```php
<?php

    $setTime = $argv[1];

    function format_time($t,$f=':') {

        return sprintf("%02d%s%02d%s%02d", floor($t/3600), $f, ($t/60)%60, $f, $t%60);

    }

    echo format_time($setTime);

?>
```

Comment: Have you started the coding, or are you hoping someone here will do it all for you

Comment: _Really not sure why someone decided this question warranted an upvote?_

Comment: @RiggsFolly The question itself is an interesting one compared to most others these days. It is just not showing any effort.

Comment: I added the code that kind of did something.

Comment: Well the first thing you are going to have to do is test the input to see which format was used so you then know how to unscramble its contents correctly

Comment: You want to first of all check whether any of the “units” is present, to determine which of the two cases you are dealing with. (I suppose a mixture of both formats would make rather little sense.) Only with the second format you can simply go from right to left to determine the factor, with the first one you have to check what the unit is in each case, and base the factor on that.

Comment: I would start by splitting this into its parts, by either a space, a colon or a combination of the two. Relatively simple regular expression, fed to `preg_split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_match_all` to split the input into pairs of numbers and suffixes and then iterate those to count the number of seconds:

```
function seconds($input) {
    preg_match_all("/(\d+)(\S)/", "$input:", $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $letters = "smhd";
    $durations = ["s" => 1, "m" => 60, "h" => 60*60, "d" => 60*60*24];
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach (array_reverse($matches) as list($all, $num, $code)) {
        $i = strpos($letters, $code);
        if ($i === false) $code = $letters[$i = 0];
        $letters = substr($letters, $i+1);
        $seconds += $durations[$code] * $num;
    }
    return $seconds;
}

function test($input) {
    $seconds = number_format(seconds($input));
    echo "$input => $seconds seconds\n";
}

test("1d 6h 20m 2s");  // 109.202 seconds
test("3:50");          // 230 seconds
test("4: 23: 45: 02"); // 431.102 seconds
test("23m");           // 1.380 seconds
```

[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/JP9M6)

Answer (score 1):

The following might be total overkill, but it also might illustrate how you can approach this problem if you want your code to be extendable and easy to reuse:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

interface TimeStringParser
{
    public function accepts(string $input): bool;

    public function parse(string $input): int;
}

final class InputWithUnits implements TimeStringParser
{
    public function accepts(string $input): bool
    {
        foreach (preg_split('/\s+/', $input) as $chunk) {
            if (! preg_match('/^\d+(d|h|m|s)$/', $chunk)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function parse(string $input): int
    {
        if (! $this->accepts($input)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid input.');
        }

        $result = 0;
        if (preg_match_all('/((?<value>\d+)(?<unit>d|h|m|s))/', $input, $matches)) {
            foreach ($matches['unit'] as $i => $unit) {
                $value = (int) $matches['value'][$i];
                switch ($unit) {
                    case 'd': $result += $value * 86400; break;
                    case 'h': $result += $value * 3600; break;
                    case 'm': $result += $value * 60; break;
                    case 's': $result += $value * 1; break;
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

final class InputWithoutUnits implements TimeStringParser
{
    public function accepts(string $input): bool
    {
        foreach (explode(':', $input) as $chunk) {
            if (! preg_match('/^\d+$/', trim($chunk))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function parse(string $input): int
    {
        if (! $this->accepts($input)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid input.');
        }

        $multiplier = [1, 60, 3600, 86400];
        $result = 0;

        foreach (array_reverse(explode(':', $input)) as $chunk) {
            $value = (int) trim($chunk);
            $result += $value * array_shift($multiplier);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

final class ParserComposite implements TimeStringParser
{
    private $parsers;

    public function __construct(TimeStringParser ...$parsers)
    {
        $this->parsers = $parsers;
    }

    public function accepts(string $input): bool
    {
        foreach ($this->parsers as $parser) {
            if ($parser->accepts($input)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function parse(string $input): int
    {
        foreach ($this->parsers as $parser) {
            if ($parser->accepts($input)) {
                return $parser->parse($input);
            }
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid input.');
    }
}

$parser = new ParserComposite(
    new InputWithUnits(),
    new InputWithoutUnits()
);

$testCases = [
    '5d 4h 3m 2s',
    '4h 2s',
    '3m',
    '05: 04: 03: 02',
    '4:03:02',
    '05: 00: 03: 02',
    '02',
    '23m',
    '2e-5'
];

foreach ($testCases as $testCase) {
    if ($parser->accepts($testCase)) {
        printf("%-'.20s: %8d\n", $testCase, $parser->parse($testCase));
    }
    else {
        printf("%-'.20s: unsupported\n", $testCase);
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/qAYqD